# JSF2 Dynamically loading pages by ajax

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I want to load pages into a central div when i click my menu links in JSF2.0. I set up a panelmenu and wrote a menu item like this.

```
<p:menuitem >
<h:commandButton value="Edit Details"  action="#{formsBean.changeDisplay(1)}">
 <f:ajax  render=":editdiv"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
</p:menuitem>
```

The component to be updated is:

```
<h:panelGroup id="editdiv" rendered="#{formsBean.edituserdiv}" layout="block">
  <ui:include src="edituserdetails.xhtml">

 </ui:include>
 </h:panelGroup>
```

The function `formsBean.changeDisplay(1)` sets `edituserdiv` to true to show the corresponding panel group.

In the included page i have a form defined.

Also in the main page i call a pre-render function to set all divs to false to show no div on first page load.

The problem is that when i click the menu item the included page is not being included. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because initially your `h:panelGroup` is not rendered so AJAX request can't find it in generated code, so it can't update it. Encapsulate it in another `h:panelGroup` and render it:

```
<h:panelGroup id="editdivParent" layout="block">
  <h:panelGroup id="editdiv" rendered="#{formsBean.edituserdiv}" layout="block">
    <ui:include src="edituserdetails.xhtml">

    </ui:include>
  </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

And change your `f:ajax` to:

```
<f:ajax  render=":editdivParent"/>
```

Comment: Thanks.. It worked.  I had to include some 4 pages. So i put all panelgroups in one enclosing panel group and rendered the enclosing one using ajax. rendering individual panelgroups resulted in the already shown ones being not hidden when new one is to be shown. Thanks a lot..