# JSF2 Dynamic form is not being submitted

Tags: jsf-2

I have a form that is defined in a separate jsf page. This is is included to the main page when i click a link. Now the form is being displayed correctly. But the problem is that the submit button is not calling the action function defined.

The code to include the page( As suggested in this question:  [JSF2 Dynamically loading pages by ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15412704/jsf2-dynamically-loading-pages-by-ajax)

```
<h:panelGroup id="editdivparent" layout="block">
 <h:panelGroup id="editdiv" rendered="#{formsBean.edituserdiv}" layout="block">
     <h:form id="userform"  class="form-horizontal"> 
  <ui:include src="edituserdetails.xhtml">

   </ui:include>
 </h:form>
</h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

The included page contains just the form elements with submit button:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{userBean.register() }"  value="Update">

</h:commandButton>
```

I am getting no errors. On submitting the form the current page is redisplayed. I have put some print statements in the action function. Also there is a query error is put. None of them are being generated.

Am i doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The `commandButton` `action` property already expects a method expression, so just take the parenthesis out, like this:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{userBean.register}" value="Update" />
```

Also, make sure you don't have nested forms when making templates with includes.

I hope it helps.

Comment: If the form was included statically, the action function is called. But if the form is not rendered at initial page load and is loaded dynamically(here ui:include) then the action function is not called. Any suggestions to submit the form loaded dynamically?